# Google Sheet Query Pivot - count if a date is between a range of dates

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table, flatten

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AQUNPb4d3EqeSZb9SwfzemR7MfSIkMFkDAZ8rPLA3rc/edit?usp=sharing

I have 3 columns :

- City
- Date start
- End date

I want 3 table :

- **Pivot Table city with people which enter during the year (Done)**
  `=query(QUERY({$A$2:$C$10};`
  `"select Col1, count(Col1)`
  `where year(Col2)=2018 or year(Col2)=2019 or year(Col2)=2020`
  `group by Col1`
  `pivot year(Col2)");`
  `"select * order by Col4 desc, Col3 desc, Col2 desc label Col1 'Start'";1)`

**Pivot Table city with people which left during the year (Done)**
`=query(QUERY({$A$2:$C$10};`
`"select Col1, count(Col1)`
`where (year(Col3)=2018 or year(Col3)=2019 or year(Col3)=2020)`
`group by Col1`
`pivot year(Col3)");`
`"select * order by Col4 desc, Col3 desc, Col2 desc label Col1 'End'";1)`

**- Pivot Table city with people which stay during the year (Fail)**
`=query(QUERY({$A$2:$C$10};`
`"select Col1, count(Col1)`
`where`
`(2018>=YEAR(Col2) and 2018<=YEAR(Col3) or`
`(2019>=YEAR(Col2) and 2019<=YEAR(Col3) or`
`(2020>=YEAR(Col2) and 2020<=YEAR(Col3)`
`group by Col1`
`pivot year(Col2)");`
`"select * order by Col4 desc, Col3 desc, Col2 desc label Col1 'Between'";1)`

For the last one, i am getting trouble.
I guess my Where condition is not adapted and my pivot not working too.

I know pivot year(Col2) can't work for the last one, because if a row got a date start 2015 and 2020 end start, i want it to be counted, but my pivot won't show up 2018 2019 2020.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: I have preliminary questions. 1.) You have ending dates of Jan 1 for most of your entries. If the end date is January 1, does that really count as having stayed during that year? For instance, given a start of Jan 1, 2018 and an end of Jan 1, 2020, was this (person?) really there for 2018, 2019 and 2020... or just for 2018 and 2019, given that the departure was on the first day of 2020? 2.) Do you need the table in Rows 21 downward, or was that just an attempt at helping with the formula? If the latter, you don't need it, and it's actually making it harder to work with the top data.

Comment: Hello Erik, 1) Well good point, if it's ending 1 january it sould not be counted, i picked up some example, bad choose ! Should be at 02/01/20XX to be counted as present during the year. I would like to get like E16:H19, in 1 query, but can not mange to make my formula work, like i did for the 2 others. Hope i make it clear. Thanks !

Comment: Likewise, if the start date is in late December, it doesn't seem that that year should be counted. Is it reasonable to say that if the start date is after Dec 15, the start year should actually be the *next* calendar year? And that if the end date is earlier than Jan 15, the end year should actually be the *previous* year? In addition, you have not yet answered my second question above: Do you need the table in Rows 21 and down?

Comment: Hello Erik, the table in Rows 21 and down are not needed. If someone spend 1 night ( january 1 to january 2,), he should be count. So if end date finish by 1 january, it should not count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C10; B2:B10)>=
 SEQUENCE(1; 5000; ); ROW(A2:A10)&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&TEXT(B2:B10+SEQUENCE(1; 5000; ); 
 "yyyy-1-1"); )); "×")); 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where year(Col3) matches '2018|2019|2020' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot year(Col3) 
  label Col2'Between'"); 
 "order by Col4 desc, Col3 desc, Col2 desc"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(DATEDIF(B2:B; C2:C; "Y")>=
 SEQUENCE(1; MAX(DATEDIF(B2:B; C2:C; "Y")); ); ROW(A2:A)&"×"&A2:A&"×"&
 YEAR(B2:B)+SEQUENCE(1; MAX(DATEDIF(B2:B; C2:C; "Y")); )&"-1-1"; )); "×"); 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where year(Col3) matches '2018|2019|2020' 
  group by Col2 
  pivot year(Col3) 
  label Col2'Between'"); 
 "order by Col4 desc, Col3 desc, Col2 desc"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello player0, thanks you for your answer. It is working in the spreasheet example but  doesn't in a larger (14 500 rows) dataset : The resulting Array was too large. Made an another sheet with 16k rows, if you manage to make it work it would be awesome (tried, it crashed the spreadsheet) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AQUNPb4d3EqeSZb9SwfzemR7MfSIkMFkDAZ8rPLA3rc/edit#gid=1743066874

Comment: @laterr2 answer updated